# Passing multiple parameters to autocomplete return method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, .net

I need some help here. I am using razor view in MVC3. I have a search bar with autocomplete feature that is working fine. Now as per the req. I need to create a radio button beside search text box and based on the radio button values selected I need to get the autocomplete text from different tables. It's because, my index page view has 3 different webgrid listing. so, search should act based on what the user intend to search by specifying the option in the parameter as radio button.

I have my regular jQuery code here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
    })
})*
```

I modified the above to pass second parameter :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var radioval = $("#form0").find("input[type=radio]").attr("value");
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function (request) {
        var srctxt = $(this).attr("value");
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: "/Facility/FindNames/?term = " + $(this).attr("value") + "&stype = " + radioval
        });
    })
})
```

My intention is to pass the second parameter search type which is a radio button group and then in the controller below based on the value passed change the query to select from different tables.

--Controller Method

```
 public JsonResult FindNames(string term, string stype)
    {

        string radioValue = null;

        var result = _service.GetAllFacility()
                    .Where(r => r.FacilityName.Contains(term))
                    .Take(10)
                    .Select(r => new { label = r.FacilityName });

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

however the value of stype is always coming as null. Using firebug I can see it does have value. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? What is the best way to implement this kind of search feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle the `source` `function` as follows to pass multiple parameters

```
var radioval = $("#form0").find("input[type=radio]").attr("value");
$(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function() {

     $this = $(this);
     var srctxt = $this.val();
     $this.autocomplete({
          source: function (request, response) {
             $.getJSON('/Facility/FindNames/',
             {
                stype: radioval,
                term: srctxt
             }, response);
          }
     });
})
```

Comment: This works but one problem, it doesn't refresh the auto-complete search text as you keep typing. Do you know?

Comment: It looks like the srctxt value, the controller is receiving as null.

Comment: This just helped me resolve an issue in ASP.NET  Core. Slight difference with the following line in the Contoller....return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    ->   return Json(result);